# Limitations of Eric van der Vlist's RelaxNG simplicification

Tags: relaxng

All,

I am trying to simplify a RelaxNG schema using [Eric van der Vlist's simplification.xsl](http://downloads.xmlschemata.org/relax-ng/utilities/simplification.xsl), but I'm getting errors:

```
runtime error: file ./simplification.xsl line 741 element element
xsl:element: The effective name '' is not a valid QName.
runtime error: file ./simplification.xsl line 751 element element
xsl:element: The effective name '' is not a valid QName.
runtime error: file ./simplification.xsl line 759 element element
xsl:element: The effective name '' is not a valid QName.
runtime error: file ./simplification.xsl line 759 element element
xsl:element: The effective name '' is not a valid QName.
runtime error: file ./simplification.xsl line 759 element element
xsl:element: The effective name '' is not a valid QName.
```

It seems it has something to do with some names getting constructed dynamically:

```
<xsl:template match="rng:start[not(preceding-sibling::rng:start) and following-sibling::rng:start]" mode="step7.18">
        <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="step7.18"/>
                <xsl:element name="{parent::*/rng:start/@combine}">
                        <xsl:call-template name="start7.18"/>
                </xsl:element>
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I haven't started getting into it any deeper, but perhaps someone already has a clue on what might be causing this.

Comment: Presumably the selected rng:start element has no @combine attribute. I can't debug the stylesheet for you, but just make an observation: in XSLT 1.0, if the name supplied to xsl:element is invalid, the effect is processor-dependent - it's one of those errors that processors can choose either to report, or to recover from. Eric may have been testing on a processor that took the recovery action.

Comment: Did you consider to ask [him](http://eric.van-der-vlist.com/blog/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I wasn't the first one to run into these issues. [This web site](http://debeissat.nicolas.free.fr/relaxng_simplification.php) also refers to some problems running simplification.xsl, and includes some fixes. I'm just copying it in here, for future reference.

> - In step 10 : prefix "rng:" was missing in lines `<xsl:with-param name="node-name" select="'rng:group'"/>` resulting with markups `<group>` with default namespace (which is not RelaxNG) in output.
> - In step 14 : add concatenation of prefix "rng:" before value of "combine" attributes in lines `<xsl:param name="node-name" select="concat('rng:',parent::*/rng:start/@combine)"/>`.
> - In step 14 : In template `<xsl:template match="rng:start[not(preceding-sibling::rng:start) and following-sibling::rng:start]">` I removed the element addition `<xsl:element name="{parent::*/rng:start/@combine}">` because it results to an extra `<rng:choice>` surrounding the other `<rng:choice>` inside the `<rng:start>`.
> - In step 15 : seems that template `<xsl:template match="/*">` has a higher priority than template `<xsl:template match="/rng:grammar">`, so I had to add a precision : `<xsl:template match="/*[not(self::rng:grammar)]">`.
> - In step 15 : missing `"rng:parentRef/@name"` in erasing template : `<xsl:template match="rng:define|rng:define/@name|rng:ref/@name|rng:parentRef/@name"/>` in order to keep the id generated in "name" attribute of `<parentRef>`.

After copying in my original RelaxNG grammar in the given web site, the whole transformation completes without any problem.

Answer (score 3):

Is there some reason not to use jing -s instead?

Comment: Possibly the fact that the only Jing documentation I can find (at https://relaxng.org/jclark/jing.html) appears not to list any -s option?

Comment: Another reason might be that jing -s appears not to produce output in simplified syntax.  (OK by me, since it produces something that's easier for me to use than RNG simplified syntax, but OP was trying to use a stylesheet intended to perform RNG simplification as described in the spec.)